# ¿Cómo puedo obtener la clase de una fila de una tabla para poder cambiar el valor de un campo mediante ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Para empezar, lo que tengo es que al presionar un botón que está en la misma fila me agarra el valor y lo suma, pero lo que no me funciona es cuando quiero mandarlo a imprimir a través de mi archivo de javascript mediante ajax,no sé como mostrarlo para cada fila. Si alguien sabe cómo hacerlo ayudenme que estoy atascado en esto.

Este es mi codigo :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3><font color="black">MENÚ DEL DIA</font></h3> <br>
    <h1 id="contenido"> </h1>
     <?php
            require("../connect_db.php");
            $sql=("SELECT m.cod_menu,p.nombre,m.estado FROM menu m inner join plato p on m.plato = p.cod_plato");

            $query=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

            echo "<table border='1'; class='table table-hover';>";
              echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>Platos</td>";
                echo "<td>Cantidad</td>";
                echo  "<td>Agregar</td>";
                echo "<td>Quitar</td>";
              echo "</tr>";
      ?>
      <?php
             while($arreglo=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                echo "<tr>";
                  echo "<td>$arreglo[1]</td>";
                  echo "<td class='carta-menu' contenteditable>0</td>";
                // echo "<td><a href='platon.php?cod_menu=$arreglo[0]&idval=1'><img src='images/11.png' class='img-rounded'/></a></td>";
                // echo "<td><a href='platon.php?cod_menu=$arreglo[0]&idval=2'><img src='images/12.png' class='img-rounded'/></a></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='image' src='../images/11.png' class='mas' class='img-rounded'></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='image' src='../images/12.png' class='menos' class='img-rounded'></td>";
                // $_SESSION['cod_menu']=$arreglo[0];
              echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
              echo "<td><a href='orden.php?'><img src='../images/9.png' class='img-rounded'></td>";
          ?>
          <script src="sumar.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

En esta parte yo estoy obteniendo el valor del campo cantidad de cada fila y luego lo muestro con ajax,pero no me muestra para cada fila sino para todas.

El sumar.js

```
$('.mas').click(function(){

    $(this).parents('tr').find('.carta-menu').each(function(){
      valor = parseInt($(this).html());
    })

    valor = valor+1;
    console.log(valor);

      $.ajax({
          data: {suma:valor},
          url: '../pruebita.php',
          type: 'post',
          beforeSend : function(){
            console.log('Se esta procesando .....');
          }
      }).done(function(data){
        //Esta parte no sé como mostrarlo para cada fila
        $('.carta-menu').text(data);
      });
  });
```

Y este es el archivo que recibe mi peticion ajax:

```
<?php
  $suma = $_POST['suma'];
  echo  $suma;
?>
```

Esta es la imagen después de presionar el primer botón como se ve se suma +1 para todas las filas

[image: Imagen después de haber presionado el primer boton]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En `Sumar.js`, no entiendo muy bien por qué utilizas la función `parents()` en bucle, cuando sólo necesitas el valor de una fila.

Por otro lado, al asignar el valor, deberías hacer lo mismo que al recuperarlo, porque si tienes n clases llamadas `carga-menu` se asignará el valor a todas ellas.

Finalmente, supongo que estarás haciendo pruebas para algo y por eso haces la llamada asíncrona porque, si es algo tan sencillo como sumar, se puede hacer todo desde javascript.

Prueba haciendo estos cambios a ver qué tal:

```
$('.mas').click(function(){

    /*$(this).parents('tr').find('.carta-menu').each(function(){
      valor = parseInt($(this).html());
    })*/

    var tableRow = $(this).parent(),
        valor = parseInt(tableRow.find('.carta-menu').html());

    valor = valor+1;
    console.log(valor);

      $.ajax({
          data: {suma:valor},
          url: '../pruebita.php',
          type: 'post',
          invokedata: { row: tableRow },
          beforeSend : function(){
            console.log('Se esta procesando .....');
          }
      }).done(function(data){
        //Esta parte no sé como mostrarlo para cada fila
        //$('.carta-menu').text(data);
        this.invokedata.row.find('.carta-menu').html(data);
      });
  });
```

Está hecho de memoria ya que no puedo hacer pruebas ahora mismo, pero sería algo así. Espero te sirva.

Comment: gracias por responder y sí ya funciona.